# Phonegap application display blank screen on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, cordova, ios6

I built application with Phonegap and Sencha Touch 2 and all works great on iOS 5.1
But on iOS 6 the application opened and display an blank screen.
Why ? How can I check it ? Do you familiar with this issue on iOS 6 with Phonegap ?

Answer (score 12):

Reset Content and Settings in IOS simulator does it. 
If your getting 'error: failed to attach to process ID 0' in logs.

Comment: Sure did.  While I had the iPad simulator in focus, from the top pull downs: `iOS Simulator > (3rd item down) Reset Content and Settings... ` got me up and running again.

Comment: Miraculously fixed mine. If only I saw this post earlier.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen using Phonegap and/or Sencha, typically a blank white screen means you have a javascript error somewhere. Javascript fails silently inside of PhoneGap, so your best solution would be to open your index.html file inside of Chrome, Safari, or Firefox with the Javascript console enabled.

This will allow you to see the error that caused the white-fail, and once you know what the issue is and fix it, you can run it on the device and you shouldn't see the white-screen anymore.